# Webpack Sass and foundation how do I manipulate the variables

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, mixins, webpack

I'm working on a project with webpack to load all my assets.

I load my assets like that in `app.js` and concat them with `ExtractTextPlugin`:

`import 'foundation-sites/scss/normalize.scss';
import 'foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss';
import './../sass/app.scss';`

I read somewhere that webpack will read each line and one by one compile to CSS and append them to my dist file.

My problem is that I want to access the variables and mixins in foundation from the app.scss, but since they are compile one after the other and appended, it doesn't seem possible to access those mixins and variables. Any one has a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You need to load your dependent `.scss` files within `app.scss`.

To do this with webpack. I've configured my `app.scss` like so:

```
@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
@import 'settings';
@include foundation-everything($flex: true);
// the rest of my imports now have access to Foundation mixins
@import 'mycomponent.scss'
```

The `~` tells `sass-loader` to tell `webpack` to [look in the modules directory for those files](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader#imports).